# How can I generate random numbers based on a pattern from a given list of numbers?

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm trying to generate x random numbers based on lists I will provide (containing the same amount of numbers I want generated).
So Far I have this code:

```
import random
list = []

while len(list) < 10:
    x = random.randint(1, 100)
    if x not in list:
        list.append(x)

list.sort()
print (list)
```

The question is, how do I input the lists I have so Python can read some pattern (in lack of a better word) and generate numbers?
Tried Google it, found nothing so far.
Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do the input lists affect the random number generation? Are you simply looking for `random.shuffle` or `random.sample`?

Comment: Have you tried regex? Regex can really help you out with patterns

Comment: You need to describe your issue more clearly. How will the list affect what numbers are put in the list? Do you want your code to recognize patterns?

Comment: As per above, how is this list supposed to affect the output?  Furthermore, what do you mean by 'input the list'?  Please give an example of the input list (including what format you currently have it in - python list, text file, csv etc), and an example of the potential output.

Answer (score 0):

With python a file can be read and split on whitespace into a list using str.split() with no argument like this:

```
lines = [] 
for line in open('filename'):
    line = line.strip().split() # splits on whitespace
        for token in line:
            lines.append(token)
```

If the file has a different separator such as a colon it can be split like above if the separator is a character or fixed sequence of characters using split('char') as in split(':') or split('charseq') as in split('==='), or it can be split on a regular expression using re.split('some_regex','text2split'). Additionally, it could be useful to verify the format of numeric data to ensure invalid data does not cause an error or other undesirable behavior in subsequent processing.

Below is a complete example for extracting comma-separated numbers from a file and appending them into a list and where the numbers are filtered to match at least one of three forms defined by regular expressons: (1) '\d+' (more than one decimal digit); (2) '\d+.\d*' (more than one decimal digit followed by a period followed by zero or more decimal digits; or (3) '\d*.\d+' (zero or more decimal digits followed by a period followed by one or more decimal digits). In this example a regex for matching numbers in these forms is compiled to improve performance.

```
import re
numList = []
regex = re.compile('^(\d+)|(\d+\.\d*)|(\d*\.\d+)$')
for data in open('filename'):
    tmpList = re.split(',',data.strip()) # could use data.strip().split(',')
    for element in tmpList:                   
    if regex.match(element):
        numList.append(element)
```

After running this the numbers in numList can be iterated like this:

```
for item in numList:
    print(item)
    # do other things such as calculations with item
```

Comment: I think you have to prepend an 'r' to the string literal or escape the backslash. Also, `str.split` doesn't work with regular expressions. There is however a split function in the `re` module.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Prepending 'r' is not needed with re.split() if the regex is single quoted according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re.split#re.split. I am using Python 2 for compability with Apache Spark.